# mySQL запрос фильтрации по параметрам, исключающий неполные совпадения

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно отобрать продукты, которые имеют все заданные параметры. 33 и 13.

```
SELECT * FROM product_options WHERE option_id IN (33,13)
```

[image: таблица]

Вышеуказанный запрос выдаёт продукты которые хотя бы по одному параметру совпадают с запросом (что логично). Всем параметрам соответствует только продукт с id = 11.

Comment: А через AND не сделать?

Comment: Можно, но результат аналогичный.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083409/mysql-how-to-select-groups-having-certain-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычное реляционное деление.

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM product_options 
WHERE option_id IN (33,13)
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT option_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Ниже еще один запрос JOIN:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM product_options po1
JOIN product_options po2 USING (product_id)
WHERE po1.option_id = 13 AND po2.option_id = 33;
```

[MySQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=8b274d97b4dfbcd248fac806d3bc2e55&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

```
+============+
| product_id |
+============+
| 11         |
+------------+
```

Comment: и как будут отличаться GROUP BY (акина выше) и JOIN если записей миллион?

Comment: Нужно у @Sebastian Melmot спросить. Пусть потестирует.